# How to run apk file online?

Tags: android, apk

Is it possible to run APK file online to check whether the file is working properly or not?..That means even if i don't have android SDK will i be able to run APK file.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390518/android-how-to-install-apk-on-device-without-using-android-sdk-tools

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773254/android-install-apk-on-phone

Comment: No i want to run it on my PC not on android device.

Comment: then you will need android SDK. open command prompt, go to SDK home/tools where you will get emulator.exe, then fire following command 'android create avd -n AVDName -t 1'  after successful creation fire another command 'emulator -avd AVDName'

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is a solution to run .apk file online. There is an online emulator [manymo.com](http://manymo.com). You can run this online but it has a limited service. You have pay for this to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Appetize provides unlimited service to run your apk online on a number of devices. Check appetize.io   [appetize.io](https://appetize.io)

Answer (score 3):

[Appetize](https://appetize.io/) and [Run That App](http://www.runthatapp.com/) are best. And they for both Android and iOS. You can customize also Android Versions to use. Appetize has also a free quota. For two concurrent users and 100 minutes a month.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/download) project. Images from there run on [Virtualbox](http://virtualbox.org) and work much faster than native Andriod emulator from SDK. Of cource [Bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com/) is more convenient. But it's Beta and sooner or later developers will ask for money.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you download a android emulator like bluestacks(http://www.bluestacks.com/) and try installing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a web service kind of thing on your server. The server should have the android sdk installed i.e. it should be able to run APK files. Your server can then stream it to the webbrowser and it can also get mouse events from the web browser and send it to server.

There is a similar app called **Cloud Browse** for iPhone/iPad on the Apple Store to be able to view flash content on the web in iPad/iPhone. Link -> http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-browse/id394418635?mt=8

So, you can get idea from this App. You can implement you own system for Android Apps as they have done for flash ! ;) All the Best ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [GenyMotion](https://genymotion.com) which emulates an Android x64 virtual device. After 1000 mins then you have to pay 5 US cents per minute, though. Not a big bill if you are only going to use it for light stuff like web surfing, etc. **Although**, it **is** actually a very powerful device. The user interface and cloud service they provide is amazing. I would use it or at least try it out to see how it goes at least if I were you.